# Long table to nested list to JSON using R and tidyverse

Tags: r, json, tidyverse

I am trying to convert a long table (eg. example below) into a nested list into a JSON using R/tidyverse and one of the JSON packages. I suspect that this can be done using split/purrr in some way but I haven't been able to figure out how exactly.

Take the following example input:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

df = data.frame(patient   = c(rep("A",4), rep("B",4)),
                sample    = rep(c("P","R"),4),
                file      = stri_rand_strings(8, 6, '[A-Z]'))
```

Which looks for example like this

```
  patient sample   file
1       A      P ZZEVYQ
2       A      R KIUXRU
3       A      P XRYBUE
4       A      R ZCHBKN
5       B      P WZYAPM
6       B      R EKDFYT
7       B      P CYEJCK
8       B      R XFAYXX
```

I would like to output something similar to this (note: manually typed).

```
[
  {
    "patient" : "A",
    "samples" : [
      {
        "sample" : "P",
        "files" : [
          {
            "file" : "ZZEVYQ"
          },
          {
            "file" : "XRYBUE"
          }
        ] 
      },
      {
        "sample" : "R",
        "files" : [
          {
            "file" : "KIUXRU"
          },
          {
            "file" : "ZCHBKN"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "patient" : "B",
    "samples" : [
      {
        "sample" : "P",
        "files" : [
          {
            "file" : "WZYAPM"
          },
          {
            "file" : "CYEJCK"
          }
          ] 
      },
      {
        "sample" : "R",
        "files" : [
          {
            "file" : "EKDFYT"
          },
          {
            "file" : "XFAYXX"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most json output, if you want nested levels, then you need to nest your data. Here's one way to achieve the nexting required to get the JSON you are after

```
dfout <- df %>% group_by(patient, sample) %>% 
  summarize(files=list(map(file, ~list(file=.x)))) %>% 
  summarize(samples=list(map2(sample, files, ~list(samples=.x, files=.y))))

jsonlite::toJSON(dfout, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Comment: Is there a way to modify this to allow any number of nestings, eg. mapN(sample, files, ...., n, ...)

Comment: You shouldn’t change a question after it’s been answered. If you have a problem not covered in your original post, it’s better to create a new post rather than completely change the question. Plus the new question will be more likely to get noticed.

Comment: OK here is the new question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477156/convert-a-tidy-table-to-deeply-nested-list-using-r-and-tidyverse