# Convert a tidy table to deeply nested list using R and tidyverse

Tags: r, json, list, tidyverse

I am trying to convert a tidy table (eg. example below) into a nested list using R/tidyverse. Using some tidyverse magic I was able to convert it to a list nested of depth three, but I cannot figure out how to nest it deeper.

Take the following example input:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

n_patient = 2
n_samples = 3
n_readgroup = 4
n_mate = 2

df = data.frame(patient   = rep(rep(LETTERS[1:n_patient], n_samples),2),
                sample    = rep(rep(seq(1:n_samples), each = n_patient),2),
                readgroup = rep(stri_rand_strings(n_patient * n_samples * n_readgroup, 6, '[A-Z]'),2),
                mate      = rep(1:n_mate, each = n_patient * n_samples * n_readgroup)) %>%
  mutate(file = sprintf("%s.%s.%s_%s", patient, sample, readgroup, mate)) %>%
  arrange(file)

json = df %>% 
  nest(-patient, .key = samples) %>%
  mutate(samples = map(samples, nest, -sample, .key=readgroups))

jsonlite::toJSON(json, pretty = T)
```

Which looks for example like this

```
> head(df)
  patient sample readgroup mate         file
1       A      1    FCSDRJ    1 A.1.FCSDRJ_1
2       A      1    FCSDRJ    2 A.1.FCSDRJ_2
3       A      1    IAXDPR    1 A.1.IAXDPR_1
4       A      1    IAXDPR    2 A.1.IAXDPR_2
5       A      1    MLDBKZ    1 A.1.MLDBKZ_1
6       A      1    MLDBKZ    2 A.1.MLDBKZ_2
```

The output looks like this:

```
 [
  {
    "patient": "A",
    "samples": [
      {
        "sample": 1,
        "readgroups": [
          {
            "readgroup": "FCSDRJ",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.1.FCSDRJ_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "FCSDRJ",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.1.FCSDRJ_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "IAXDPR",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.1.IAXDPR_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "IAXDPR",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.1.IAXDPR_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "MLDBKZ",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.1.MLDBKZ_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "MLDBKZ",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.1.MLDBKZ_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "OMTWHK",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.1.OMTWHK_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "OMTWHK",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.1.OMTWHK_2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sample": 2,
        "readgroups": [
          {
            "readgroup": "BHAEFA",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.2.BHAEFA_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "BHAEFA",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.2.BHAEFA_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "DIBRHT",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.2.DIBRHT_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "DIBRHT",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.2.DIBRHT_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "HHMOSV",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.2.HHMOSV_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "HHMOSV",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.2.HHMOSV_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "KJXTPN",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.2.KJXTPN_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "KJXTPN",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.2.KJXTPN_2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sample": 3,
        "readgroups": [
          {
            "readgroup": "CHXJMM",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.3.CHXJMM_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "CHXJMM",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.3.CHXJMM_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "MDWRBS",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.3.MDWRBS_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "MDWRBS",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.3.MDWRBS_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "RHHKGK",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.3.RHHKGK_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "RHHKGK",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.3.RHHKGK_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "VVVJFD",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "A.3.VVVJFD_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "VVVJFD",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "A.3.VVVJFD_2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "patient": "B",
    "samples": [
      {
        "sample": 1,
        "readgroups": [
          {
            "readgroup": "QAFCOS",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.1.QAFCOS_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "QAFCOS",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.1.QAFCOS_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "TJYYMQ",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.1.TJYYMQ_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "TJYYMQ",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.1.TJYYMQ_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "YMHWOI",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.1.YMHWOI_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "YMHWOI",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.1.YMHWOI_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "ZOMSBU",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.1.ZOMSBU_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "ZOMSBU",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.1.ZOMSBU_2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sample": 2,
        "readgroups": [
          {
            "readgroup": "CZWHXP",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.2.CZWHXP_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "CZWHXP",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.2.CZWHXP_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "MIMMNH",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.2.MIMMNH_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "MIMMNH",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.2.MIMMNH_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "RCWMQY",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.2.RCWMQY_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "RCWMQY",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.2.RCWMQY_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "WDMLHE",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.2.WDMLHE_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "WDMLHE",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.2.WDMLHE_2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "sample": 3,
        "readgroups": [
          {
            "readgroup": "DWITMU",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.3.DWITMU_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "DWITMU",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.3.DWITMU_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "GCLWMA",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.3.GCLWMA_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "GCLWMA",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.3.GCLWMA_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "QZZKQB",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.3.QZZKQB_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "QZZKQB",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.3.QZZKQB_2"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "WJKGRB",
            "mate": 1,
            "file": "B.3.WJKGRB_1"
          },
          {
            "readgroup": "WJKGRB",
            "mate": 2,
            "file": "B.3.WJKGRB_2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which is great, except that I also want to nest by "mate" (and in theory nest by any number of variables, without any depth limitation). Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1st step is to notice you're doing it backward, this gives the same output as yours but is simpler:

```
json2 <- df %>% nest(-(1:2),.key=readgroups) %>% nest(-1,.key=samples)
```

Then we can expand it:

```
json3 <- df %>% nest(-(1:3),.key=mate) %>% nest(-(1:2),.key=readgroups) %>% nest(-1,.key=samples)

jsonlite::toJSON(json3,pretty=T)
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "patient": "A",
    "samples": [
      {
        "sample": 1,
        "readgroups": [
          {
            "readgroup": "FUPEYR",
            "mate": [
              {
                "mate": 1,
                "file": "A.1.FUPEYR_1"
              },
              {
                "mate": 2,
                "file": "A.1.FUPEYR_2"
              }
...
```

And if necessary, generalize it:

```
vars <- names(df)[-1] # or whatever variables you want to nest, order matters!
var_pairs <- map((length(vars)-1):1,~vars[.x:(.x+1)])
json4 <- reduce(var_pairs,~{nm<-.y[1];nest(.x,.y,.key=!!enquo(nm))},.init=df)

jsonlite::toJSON(json4,pretty=T)
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "patient": "A",
    "sample": [
      {
        "sample": 1,
        "readgroup": [
          {
            "readgroup": "FUPEYR",
            "mate": [
              {
                "mate": 1,
                "file": "A.1.FUPEYR_1"
              },
              {
                "mate": 2,
                "file": "A.1.FUPEYR_2"
              }
...
```

Comment: Very nice! Thanks for this answer, I figured it would make more sense starting from the innermost nesting level somehow and had tried some stuff but that did not work. Your answer works perfectly, thanks.

Hoping this is useful for others too, I found the documentation/examples dealing with nested lists in tidyverse to be a bit lacking.